# HAProxy and Mysql Cluster Topology

Tags: mysql, haproxy, mysql-cluster

I've installed mysql cluster with 2 data node,2 sqlnode and one management server on different hosts.In addition I've 3 different app instances.

Now I want to install haproxy in front of mysql cluster but not sure about topology.I searched on google but confused a lot more since most of the examples use additional components like galera cluster etc.
Should I install HAProxy on a different host or HAProxy must be on the same  host with app instaces or sqlnodes?I read that each one has pros and cons about latency they introduced but I wonder which one is more accepted and used ?or any reference or tutorial on this? (Apps are written in php running on centos 6 32bit  by the way)

Comment: check this it may help http://www.alexwilliams.ca/blog/2009/08/10/using-haproxy-for-mysql-failover-and-redundancy/